# calling levelplot from a function

Tags: r, lattice

Very weird behavior using levelplot inside a function:

```
> foo <- function() { require(lattice); levelplot(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)) }
> bar <- function() { require(lattice); levelplot(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)); return(1) }
> foo()  ## graph gets generated
Loading required package: lattice
> graphics.off()
> bar()  ## NO GRAPH GETS GENERATED
[1] 1
```

foo() works as expected, and bar() does not generate any plot.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is a duplicate, although a subtle one. `foo` actually returns the result of `levelplot`, which is then implicitly printed when run at the console.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the function returns the last generated object. In function `foo`, this is the plot. In function `bar`, it's `1`.

If you want to generate a plot *and* return another object, you have to create the plot with `print`.

```
bar <- function() { 
         require(lattice); 
         print(levelplot(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))); 
         return(1) }
```

When you call `bar()`, the plot will be created and `1` will be returned.